# Vector or element causing a segfault?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault in my program and gdb tells me it is in this function on the line of

```
parent->getChildren().push_back(temp);
```

in

```
void Tree::add(Position& value, Node*& parent) {
    Node* temp = new Node(value, parent);
    parent->getChildren().push_back(temp);
}
```

I have added cout statements before that line and everything seems to be valid when the function is called. But I don't think my vector can be invalid? The vector declaration is here -

```
std::vector<Node*> children;
```

with getChildren() just returning std::vector&. Any help is appreciated.

Node constructor:

```
Tree::Node::Node(Position& v, Node*& p)
    : value(v), parent(p), gvalue(0), hvalue(0), fvalue(0) {}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Node*& parent` is what you want?

Comment: Are you sure `parent` is not getting deleted before you make this function call?

Comment: Can you give the constructor detail for `Node(value, parent)` ?

Comment: "*with getChildren() just returning std::vector&*" How is it returning that `std::vector&`? If it's allocated on the stack and a reference is returned, that could cause a segfault quite readily.

Comment: @ildjarn, I think `getChildren()` returns class data member `children` inside the the whatever `class` of `parent`, so it should be valid.

Comment: Yes, I added this cout before calling the function

'code'cout<<"\ncalling add with n.getValue():"<<n.getValue().toString()<<" and current: "<<current;

tree.add(n.getValue(), current);
'code'

and a cout of parent before the two statements in the function, and then another in between them and the pointer values are the same for all of them.

Comment: iammilind,

Tree::Node::Node(Position& v, Node*& p) : value(v), parent(p), gvalue(0), hvalue(0), fvalue(0) {}

The member declarations in the .h are - private:
double gvalue;
double hvalue;
double fvalue;

Position value;
Node* parent;
std::vector<Node*> children;

Comment: yes I meant to put std::vector<Node*>& as the return value for getChildren and children is a vector inside of the Node class

Comment: @Sterling, if you are storing `parent` already inside the `class Tree` then why do you pass it to the `Tree::add` ? Is that a different `parent` variable ? Smells to be a dangling pointer issue somewhere ..

Comment: I am storing parent in the Node class which is a nested class inside of Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be an "element problem" because you just `push_back(Node*)`. That can't fail.

So I see 2 possible "vector problems":

1. Problem with `parent->` because `parent` is not allocated.
2. Problem with `getChildren().` because it returns a reference to non-existing vector.

Try to check both of them.

Comment: I changed multiple things to get the program working, but I think the second thing here was the problem. Basically, I had a priority queue using a c style pointer for nodes, but my Node() constructor did nothing. I changed the c style pointer to a vector and some other code to accommodate for it and this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
void Tree::add(Position& value, Node*& parent) 
{
    if (parent == NULL)
    {
        std::err << "Error Null parent. Aborting\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    Node* temp = new Node(value, parent);
    parent->getChildren().push_back(temp);
}
```